# How can I use Hping for OS detection?

Tags: networking, linux-networking

I want use [Hping](http://www.hping.org/) for detecting Host operating system but I can't find how can I do this?

I can do the same job with [Nmap](http://nmap.org/) like this:

```
nmap -O Host_IP/Name
```

Answer (score 2):

Fail. In hping no such functionality.

nonsense:

> hpinging windows box without using --winid option you will see as increments are 256 multiple because different id byteordering. This can be really usefull for OS fingerprinting:

```
#hping win95 -r
HPING win95 (eth0 192.168.4.41): NO FLAGS are set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes
46 bytes from 192.168.4.41: flags=RA seq=0 ttl=128 id=47371 win=0 rtt=0.5 ms
46 bytes from 192.168.4.41: flags=RA seq=1 ttl=128 id=+256 win=0 rtt=0.5 ms
46 bytes from 192.168.4.41: flags=RA seq=2 ttl=128 id=+256 win=0 rtt=0.6 ms
46 bytes from 192.168.4.41: flags=RA seq=3 ttl=128 id=+256 win=0 rtt=0.5 ms
```

Comment: However, on hping.org it says: Remote OS fingerprinting ?

Comment: @Laurent I update answer =)

Answer (score 1):

Try xprobe2
usage: xprobe2 [options] target

Options:

```
      -v                       Be verbose

      -r                       Show route to target(traceroute)

      -p <proto:portnum:state> Specify portnumber, protocol and state.

                               Example: tcp:23:open, UDP:53:CLOSED

      -c <configfile>          Specify config file to use.

      -h                       Print this help.

      -o <fname>               Use logfile to log everything.

      -t <time_sec>            Set initial receive timeout or roundtrip time.

      -s <send_delay>          Set packsending delay (milseconds).

      -d <debuglv>             Specify debugging level.

      -D <modnum>              Disable module number <modnum>.

      -M <modnum>              Enable module number <modnum>.

      -L                       Display modules.

      -m <numofmatches>        Specify number of matches to print.

      -T <portspec>            Enable TCP portscan for specified port(s).

                               Example: -T21-23,53,110

      -U <portspec>            Enable UDP portscan for specified port(s).

      -f                       force fixed round-trip time (-t opt).

      -F                       Generate signature (use -o to save to a file).

      -X                       Generate XML output and save it to logfile specified
```

with -o.

```
      -B                       Options forces TCP handshake module to try to guess
```

open TCP port

```
      -A                       Perform analysis of sample packets gathered during
```

portscan in

```
                               order to detect suspicious traffic (i.e. transparent
```

proxies,

```
                               firewalls/NIDSs resetting connections). Use with -T.
```